# perl error: no 'new' method in 'Statistics::Descriptive"

Tags: perl, perl-module

I installed the "Statistics::Descriptive" module using cpan then test the example:

```
use Statistics::Descriptive;
$stat = new Statistics::Descriptive;
$stat->AddData(1,2,3,4);
```

But it shows error: `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Statistics::Descriptive" at ...` I am doing it in Linux Ubuntu with Perl version 5.10.1 and the newest Statistics::Descriptive as what cpan tells me.

I tried on windows using activestate perl and it works.

Do you have any idea why I got this error when running in Linux? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive) it looks like you need to do either

```
use Statistics::Descriptive;
my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
```

or

```
use Statistics::Descriptive;
my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Sparse->new();
```

As is says: "With the sparse method, none of the data is stored and only a few statistical measures are available. Using the full method, the entire data set is retained and additional functions are available."

Perhaps you have an older version on windows.  Older versions had an *undocumented* top level new() method.

Comment: Thanks ysth. Seems this line of code is passed though by using `my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();` or `Sparse`. However, it seems there is no object method can be found in the package and shows: `Can't locate object method "AddData" via package "Statistics::Descriptive::Sparse" at ...`. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @Kenneth: I think you mean add_data; does AddData really work on windows?  even the very very old versions still on cpan don't have an AddData.

Comment: The one on windows works for this code example:
`use Statistics::Descriptive;`
`$stat = new Statistics::Descriptive;`
`$stat->AddData(1,2,3,4);`
`$mean = $stat->Mean();`
`$var  = $stat->Variance();`
`$tm  =  $stat->TrimmedMean(.25);`
as in the `Statistics::Descriptive` downloading page.

Then do you have some good examples for me to follow? Thanks ysth.

Comment: @Kenneth: just the examples in the doc I linked to at the beginning of my answer; I don't know what you mean by downloading page.

Comment: Oops... Sorry that I didn't pay attention to the link. Ok.. i know what's my problem. I was reading the downloading page of an older version of Statistics::Descriptive. Now all are working perfectly now. Thanks a lot ysth!!

Comment: @Kenneth: I'm really curious to know where you are finding this older downloading page.  Update: found it; there's a 16-year-old StatisticsDescriptive distribution on CPAN in addition to the authorized Statistics-Descriptive distribution.